# In Windows 10, is there a way to configure the taskbar order to be the same as the order the windows appear?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

By default on Windows 10, for a given program like Firefox, if you have 5 different windows of that program open, in the taskbar, when you hover over the icon, thumbnails for those windows show up in the order in which they were opened.  Is there a way to change this functionality so that these thumbnails instead show up in the order that the windows appear on the desktop?  So for instance, if I have a Firefox window open at 200px from the left of the monitor and one open at 400px from the left, then the thumbnails show up in the order of the 200px window first, followed by the 400px one?  Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps, if you can rewrite Windows.